# data structures related to coupon claim logic

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Assume we are generating coupons for customer  - each coupon having an id and expiry date , we want to design a program to allow the customers to claim their coupon . In particular we do not intend to use any backing database but need to have the scalability to handle millions of coupons - key logic should prevent a coupon from getting claimed twice

Primarily I am trying to understand the best data structure to maintain the state of coupoun ie whether it has been already claimed or not - i know there are options like bitmap , hashmap , b-tree - i wanted to understand which would be most optimal

Comment: and what's your actual programming question?

Comment: question is to create subroutine which takes as argument coupon id and returns whether it has been already claimed or not or whether it has expired

Comment: That's not a question; that is a begging work description. Write your own code!

Comment: hi , basically wanted to understand the best data structure for mainitaing whether  coupon has been claimed or not

Comment: I kinda hate when people just blindly put negative vote just because its not programming question.. I mean heck.. its tagged as "algorithm" .. how can you have a "programming" question in "algorithm"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was thinking of something like this - generate a coupon id which is something like ( issue date + Expiry date + running counter (separate series 1... N for each issue/expiry date pair) + checksum ) then have something like HashMap ( ExpiryDate => HashMap ( IssueDate , BTree )) ...the Btree would be stored the claimed counters corresponding to the coupons which have been claimed

In my approach , what we do is we generate the coupon id , so that the within the coupon id , i encode the coupon issue date and the coupon expiry date and an incremental counter value - 1,2 ....N ,Ex. Coupon 20120401-20120410-12345-XYZ , then i maintain only the counters which have been claimed for each issue date/expiry date pair in the BTree ...this Btree instead of having 1 number for each counter claimed will be storing a range of counter values claimed. there will be 1 Btree for each issue/expiry date pair.

but this Btree would have each node as ( N1 , N2) where all numbers beween N1 <= N2 have been claimed , we insert into the btree a new node if it not contibuous with any existing node else merge it to an existing node if it is contiguous and update either N1 or N2

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do such a thing without having a storage mechanism.
You need an algorithm that validates a coupon code. After it is used, you need to set a flag in your database for that coupon code, so nobody can use the same coupon twice.

So table structure will be something like:

TABLE COUPONS

COUPONCODE : nvarchar(80)
ISUSED : bit
EXPIRYDATE : datetime

Comment: i want to use an in memory data structure

Comment: using database would be two slow - i will be encoding the expiry date withing the coupon id

Answer (score 0):

can you maintain two files? In the first file, create an inverted index of all the coupon ids that are going to expire on each day.
so you will have something like this {mm/dd/yyyy:[ products which will expire on this mm/dd/yyyy]...}(so this is like key/value pairs where value is a list.. 
And second one is dictionary where you can have a hashmap with coupon_id as key and boolean as value which indicates whether you the coupon is sold or not..

And you update your second hashmap daily based on the triggered response from the first map.
So something like this..

```
hashmap 1 :{ Today_date:[1234,2345,42234]....tomorrows date:[43225,2508502..]}
```

So this indicates which coupons are going to expire today and tomorrow.. and so on

```
hashamp 2:{ 1234:1, 2345:0....}
```

1 might mean that coupon is already sold..

But after today date passes on.. 
You return the products [1234,2345,42234...] as these are the coupons set to expire.. and in hashmap2: set the value of coupons who have "0" as their value to be -1 or something.. meaning they are not available anymore.. 
so in hashmap 2 only the coupon ids which have 0 value are available..??

Comment: hmmm.. i was thinking of something like this - generate a coupon id which is something like ( issue date + Expiry date + running counter (separate series  1... N for each issue/expiry date pair) + checksum )  then have something like HashMap ( ExpiryDate => HashMap ( IssueDate , BTree ))  ...the Btree would be stored the claimed counters corresponding to the coupons which have been claimed ,

Comment: but this Btree would have each node as ( N1 , N2)  where all numbers beween N1 <= N2 have been claimed , we insert into the btree a new node if it not contibuous with any existing node else merge it to an existing node if it is contiguous and update either N1 or N2

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand your approach. I guess, it would work.. but correct me if i am wrong..but if you pass The Btree in your  hashmap, and you do this for all the coupon ids.. wont it be very expensive?? 
Inverted index is something which is used in search engines where the words are the key and the values are list of document where that word is found... so if something like this works for search engine giants.. then it should work with you as well .but again there are many ways to do this.. pick the one you think are easy for you assuming the performance is same for alternatives

Comment: In my approach , what we do is we generate the coupon id , so that the within the coupon id , i encode the coupon issue date and the coupon expiry date and an incremental counter value - 1,2 ....N ,Ex. Coupon 20120401-20120410-12345-XYZ  , then i maintain only the counters which have been claimed for each issue date/expiry date pair in the BTree  ...this Btree instead of having 1 number for each counter claimed will be storing a range of counter values claimed. there will be 1 Btree for each issue/expiry date pair.